# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pycharm

Возникла проблема с интерпретатором python 3.12.1 в PyCharm.

В коде подсвечивается элемент, который помечает как "Cannot find reference '|' in 'function' ":

```
def _hours(self, start: _time | None, end: _time | None) -> int:
```

В результате запуска программы, возникает такая ошибка:

```
def _hours(self, start: _time | None, end: _time | None) -> int:
                          ~~~~^~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'NoneType'
```

Лишние интерпретаторы удаляла, несколько раз переустанавливала python, по новому загружала все необходимые библиотеки из файла  requirements.txt. Все пути до интерпретатора корректны.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить данный баг? У моих коллег всё работает, вне зависимости от версии PyCharm.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вы уверены в этом операторе `|`? Что он по вашему должен делать?

Comment: Это побитовая замена ИЛИ (or). На вход функция получает _time или None

Comment: @SwaD в аннотации типа — обозначать, что переменная может принимать несколько типов из перечисленных здесь. Но из-за того, что аннотации типов прикручены к питону кривыми костылями, это срабатывает не всегда

Comment: Если в самом начале файла сделать `from __future__ import annotations`, то ошибка должна пропасть (хотя есть небольшой шанс, что сломается что-нибудь ещё)

Comment: _time в аннотации типа должно быть типом (или классом), судя по ошибке - у вас это функция. Добавьте больше кода, как минимум чтобы было понятно, что такое _time